# Swift - Switch multiple local html files in the same webview with Segmented control

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I have one webview in my view controller. How can I switch between 3 local html files in this webview with a segmented control?

My code for 1 html local file to load it in the webview is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

func loadAddressURL() {
  let requestURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("page1", withExtension: "html")
  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
  WebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Segmented Control, with three sections, as shown in picture:

[image: Segmented Control]

Once you have that, wire up an action to your VC and use this code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    @IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let segmentedControl = sender as UISegmentedControl

        var url = ""
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            url = "page1"
        case 1:
            url = "page2"
        case 3:
            url = "page3"
        default:
            url = "defaultPage"
        }

        loadAddressURL(url)
    }

    func loadAddressURL(page: String) {
        let requestURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(page, withExtension: "html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        WebView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to save the choice by user like this video :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3gwIhLyyMo 
code: https://github.com/awseeley/Swift-Saving-Settings-Prefrences-UserDefaults-Tutorial
but in my case I don't know what should insert in : override func viewDidLoad() , any help please ? @DiegoFreniche

Comment: If this a different problem you're having (in this case saving NSUserDefaults), first search through SO, tons of times these questions have been answered. If you didn't find the right one, post a question

Answer (score 1):

Segmented controls have a `UIControlEventValueChanged` event when the segment changes. You can wire up an action here for when the user taps on a new segment, check the currently selected index, and then update the web view.